How to stop/slowdown producer actor from over flooding consumer mailbox
In a simple scenario, I have a producer that send messages to a consumer, over flooding its mailbox. How can I know how many messages are in a specific actor's mailbox and according to that value, stop the producer actor until that number decreased?
While searching I found it is possible to access system metrics and one of them is caf.actor.mailbox-size. I also found something about streams but have no clue how to use them nor how can they solve this issue.
I tried to build this small demo, without success, where I try to read the system metric caf.actor.mailbox-size
caf-application.conf
caf {
  metrics-filters {
    actors {
      includes = [ "consumer" ]
      excludes = [ "" ]
    }
  }
}

check_mailbox_size.cpp
// How to run: ./check_mailbox_size --config-file="../test_material/caf-application.conf"

#include "caf/all.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace caf;
using namespace std::literals;

struct consumer_state {
  static inline const char* name = "consumer";

  behavior make_behavior() {
    return {
      [this](add_atom) { 
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
          return;
        },
    };
  }
};

void caf_main(actor_system& system, actor_system_config& cfg) {
  
  caf::span<const std::string> include_actors = system.metrics_actors_includes();
  std::cout << "Size Include:" << include_actors.size() << " " << include_actors[0] << std::endl;

  telemetry::gauge<int64_t>* counter = system.metrics().gauge_instance("caf", "actor",
                                       {{"mailbox-size", "name"}},
                                       "Number of HTTP requests.");

  auto a1 = system.spawn(actor_from_state<consumer_state>);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    anon_send(a1, add_atom_v);
    std::cout << "Message in queue: " << counter->value() << std::endl;
  }
  
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize the global type information before anything else.
  // init_global_meta_objects<...>();
  core::init_global_meta_objects();
  // Create the config.
  actor_system_config cfg;
  // Read CLI options.
  cfg.parse(argc, argv);
  // Return immediately if a help text was printed.
  // if (cfg.cli_helptext_printed)
  //   return 0;
  // Create the actor system.
  actor_system sys{cfg};
  // Run user-defined code.
  caf_main(sys, cfg);
}

When I compile the file I get the error:
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class caf::telemetry::metric_registry’ 30 |   telemetry::gauge<int64_t>* counter = system.metrics().gauge_instance("caf", "actor"
First of all, the way I am reading a custom config file sounds over complicated, if you have a better suggestion please tell.
The issue of the code is here   telemetry::gauge<int64_t>* counter = system.metrics().gauge_instance("caf", "actor", {{"mailbox-size", "name"}}, "Number of HTTP requests.");
I checked the source code and I cannot get what I am doing wrong.
In order to run the code with the custom config file you should do
`./check_mailbox_size --config-file="path_to/caf-application.conf"
Notes
If I have more actors can I know the amount of messages in the mailbox per actor using this approach?
If not what alternatives do I have?
Edit 1
Thanks for the comments Neverlord. I will give more insight to the final application I am trying to build.
Essentially, my producer will stream images from a camera periodically (every 100ms for example) to my consumer which will process those received images (time consuming processing). There is a high chance I will spam my consumer with messages since the producer throughput is much higher than the consumer. Thus the need to have some kind of feedback mechanism.
Do you think caf::streams are suitable for such a use case?
During today I built another demo (using your suggestion self->mailbox.size()) where I tried to create this feedback the results are strange, maybe you know why this happens.
#include "caf/all.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <span>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

using namespace caf;
using namespace std::literals;

actor producer;

struct producer_state {
  producer_state(event_based_actor* self_ , actor consumer_ ): self(self_), consumer(consumer_) {};

  int32_t period {100}; // miliseconds
  int8_t clock_id {0}; // Not important
  event_based_actor* self;
  actor consumer;
  int32_t counter {0};
  bool pause {false};

  behavior make_behavior() {

    self->mail(clock_id).send(self);
    return {
      [this](int8_t clock_id_){
        
        if (pause){
          self->println("Producer Paused");
          return;
        }
        
        self->mail(++counter).send(consumer);
        self->println("Producer is sending {}", std::to_string(counter));

        self->mail(clock_id).delay(std::chrono::milliseconds(period)).send(self);
      },

        [this](bool val) {

          if (!val && pause){
            pause = false;
            self->mail(clock_id).send(self);
            self->println("Pause to false");
          }
          else if (val && !pause) {
            pause = true;
            self->println("Pause to true");
          }
        },
    };
  }

};

behavior consumer(event_based_actor* self) {

  return {
    [self](int32_t val) {
      self->println("Consumer receives: {} with Mailbox size: {}", std::to_string(val), std::to_string(self->mailbox().size()));

      if(self->mailbox().size() >= 8){
        self->mail(true).send(producer);
      }
      else if(self->mailbox().size() < 4){
        self->mail(false).send(producer);
      }

      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    },
  };
};

void caf_main(actor_system& sys) {

  auto consumer_actor = sys.spawn(consumer);
  producer = sys.spawn(actor_from_state<producer_state> , consumer_actor);
  std::puts("Finish spawning actors");

  sys.await_all_actors_done();
}

// creates a main function for us that calls our caf_main
CAF_MAIN()


Here I try to pause/play the producer depending on the mailbox size.
When I run this I get the following output
Finish spawning actors
Producer is sending 1
Consumer receives: 1 with Mailbox size: 0
Producer is sending 2
Producer is sending 3
Producer is sending 4
Producer is sending 5
Producer is sending 6
Producer is sending 7
Producer is sending 8
Producer is sending 9
Producer is sending 10
Consumer receives: 2 with Mailbox size: 8
Consumer receives: 3 with Mailbox size: 7
Consumer receives: 4 with Mailbox size: 6
Consumer receives: 5 with Mailbox size: 5
Consumer receives: 6 with Mailbox size: 4
Consumer receives: 7 with Mailbox size: 3
Consumer receives: 8 with Mailbox size: 2
Consumer receives: 9 with Mailbox size: 1
Consumer receives: 10 with Mailbox size: 0
Pause to true
Producer Paused
Pause to false
Producer is sending 11
Consumer receives: 11 with Mailbox size: 0
Producer is sending 12
Consumer receives: 12 with Mailbox size: 0
Producer is sending 13
Consumer receives: 13 with Mailbox size: 0
Producer is sending 14
Consumer receives: 14 with Mailbox size: 0
Producer is sending 15
Consumer receives: 15 with Mailbox size: 0
Producer is sending 16

In theory the producer is running at 100ms period and the consumer takes 1 sec to process the message, however if the mailbox size is above 8 it should pauses the producer and if bellow 4 it should play the producer. However the logs are strange:

When we see Producer is sending 10 seems like the consumer automatically pauses the producer which only resumes when consumer finished its mailbox
After that point, the producer sends data at the same frequency as the consumer even though the producer's period should be 100ms not 1 sec

I find these very strange.
I know this feedback approach is not the way to go, I was just curious about what is happening here.


... I have a producer that send messages to a consumer, over flooding its mailbox. How can I know how many messages are in a specific actor's mailbox and according to that value, stop the producer actor until that number decreased?

Looking at the mailbox size won't help. The receiver has no control over the sender, so it cannot block or "unschedule" it. There needs to be some kind of protocol between sender and receiver to communicate how much messages can be consumed / buffered. This can be done explicitly in your code, essentially by having the source "register" itself by the sink and then the sink can actively pull more items from the source as it sees fit.
However, if you are producing a sequence of values, I would suggest looking into the stream/flow API. Here's a small example how it generally looks like:
caf::behavior source(caf::event_based_actor* self) {
  return {
    [self](caf::get_atom) {
      return self->make_observable()
        .iota(1)
        .take(5)
        .to_stream("int-flow", max_batch_delay, max_batch_size);
    }
  };
}

// someplace later, e.g., in main

// Get the stream handle from the source actor.
caf::stream items;
caf::scoped_actor self{sys};
self->request(sys.spawn(source), caf::infinite, caf::get_atom_v)
     .receive([&items](caf::stream& res) mutable { items = std::move(res); },
              [](const caf::error& err) { println("error: ", err); });
if (!items.source()) {
  println("failed to get a valid stream handle");
  return;
}

// Subscribe an actor to the stream and wait for it to complete.
auto src1 = sys.spawn([items](caf::event_based_actor* src) {
  src->observe_as<int>(items, max_buffered, demand_threshold)
    .map([](int value) { return value * 2;})
    .for_each([](int x) { println("source-1: ", x); });
});


That's an exempt from this article: https://www.cafcademy.com/articles/flows-part-1. The article will also explain how things work internally.

error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class caf::telemetry::metric_registry’

As a side note: if you have an incomplete type in C++, it means the proper #include is missing. That particular class is defined in caf/telemetry/metric_registry.hpp.
However, reading metrics from the registry that CAF registers itself is unsafe. In this case, it is also unnecessary, since an actor can obtain (an estimate of) the current size of its mailbox via self->mailbox().size().

Thanks for the comments neverlord, I edited my post with the odd results of an experiment I did. If you could take a look would be perfect :)

You are probably observing an artifact from the scheduler that comes from blocking a thread for a long time via std::sleep_for. If you have actors that can occupy a thread for a long time, you can try spawning it with sys.spawn<caf::detached>(...) and see if that improves the behavior.However, CAF uses work stealing, so the other scheduler threads should pick up items from the busy worker if they have nothing to do.
